# Batch File - Search for any folder containing text, proceed when none are found

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, error-handling

What I would like to do is search a directory for any subfolder containing `.NA`.

> ```
> Example  
> Folder1  
> Folder2  
> Folder3.NA
> ```

As long as there is a folder with `.NA` do nothing. When there is no longer any folders with `.NA` delete a file in a different folder.

Each time this code runs, I never get to the `:NotFound` section to execute deleting the file.
Maybe someone has a different solution than what I'm thinking of.

Here is my Code - this will run at startup:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set Source=C:\Temp\Users

FOR /d %%a in ("%Source%\*.NA") DO (
    IF NOT !ErrorLevel! == 0 GOTO NotFound
    IF !ErrorLevel! == 0 GOTO Found  REM  - There is still a user folder with .NA
)
Goto EOF

:Found
@echo There is a folder with .NA Do Nothing

Goto EOF

:NotFound
@echo Simulate delete start-up file

Goto EOF

:EOF
PAUSE
```

Comment: There is nothing to check the `ErrorLevel` of (I believe `for` does not touch it); you could simply use `set "FLAG=" & for /D %%A in ("%Source%\*.NA") do set "FLAG=found"` instead of your `for /D` loop, and just query `if defined FLAG (goto :Found) else (goto :NotFound)` afterwards... you actually want to check if a folder *ends with `.NA`*, right?

Comment: For /d with a wildcard will return matching folders if found, so put just a goto :found behind the the do. There is no errorlevel from the for. If no find the flow continues with the next statement - remove the goto Eof following the unecessary parentheses.

Comment: Good idea, @LotPings, I should have noticed... You need to replace the `goto :EOF` by `goto :NotFound` though, because smply removing it whould let execution continue at `:Found`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put aschipfl's and my suggestions into code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set Source=C:\Temp\Users
FOR /d %%a in ("%Source%\*.NA") DO Goto :Found
::fall through with no find
@echo Simulate delete start-up file
Goto :End

:Found
@echo There is a folder with .NA Do Nothing

:End
PAUSE
```

If you you need an own exit point with a pause command don't call it eof, that is an internal automatic label.